# T4 template to generate stored procedure code using poco.Has anybody done it?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity, t4

Moving towards poco and wondering if anybody has written a template to generate stored procedure code when using poco in EF4?

I dont mean the sql code ,I mean the actual c# code that talks to Sql server.

That would be fantastic!!!

any suggestions or link would be wonderful

Comment: Provide some code that we'll be able to see what exactly you'd like to have... I've done some SP integration with T4 but on BLToolkit. http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/11/t4-template-to-generate-bltoolkit.html

Comment: why would you want to generate it? It's a 1 liner: `Context.ExecuteFunction<YourSPReturnType>("YourStoreContainer.YourSPName")`

Comment: Thanks for your replies.@RPM1984 what about if you have parameters eg output or a proc with 15 parameters surely we must create them.Sorry if Iam missing the obvious.About todo some reading.Yesterday I started learning poco.@Robert did not put code as i though it was a generic thing. You have 10 procs some are insert some are update etc and would like to generate the code.TBH i dont know much about poco.Apologies if explanation is no good

Comment: Why do you want to use Stored Procs? Most EF projects use direct table access.

Answer (score 0):

Try the EF's Database SqlQuery

```
public class SpecificationAdHocQuery<T> : ISpecificationAdHocQuery<T> where T : class
{
    protected string Sql;
    protected object[] Parameters;

    protected SpecificationAdHocQuery()
    {
    }

    public SpecificationAdHocQuery(string sql, params object[] parameters)
    {
        Sql = sql;
        Parameters = parameters;
    }

    public T ExecuteAdHocQueryReturnsEntity(Database database)
    {
        return database == null ? default(T) : database.SqlQuery<T>(Sql, Parameters).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IQueryable<T> ExecuteAdHocQueryReturnsEntities(Database database)
    {
        return database == null ? default(IQueryable<T>) : database.SqlQuery<T>(Sql, Parameters).AsQueryable();
    }
```